# Rails production deployment folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I noticed that when I set my Rails app to production it created a folder in my application called `RAILS_ENV=production` I've kinda rolled back now and not pushing to production. Am I free to delete this folder?

Comment: That shouldn't happen, I'd inspect your config files, particularly `environments/production.rb` to see if there's anything odd there that might be creating this.

Comment: It has :( I definitely didnt create it! The directory structure is as follows: "RAILS_ENV=production/ruby/1.8/" then in here I have bin, cache, doc, gems and specifications folders. The environment files look ok to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now fixed this issue, there was a 'PATH' setting in my bundler config file that kept re-creating the folder when I updated my bundle. I removed the path declaration and now it uses the default path.

Answer (score 0):

The "rails" command in Rails 2 creates a new app, while the same in Rails 3 runs script/... so it looks like you've installed an old version of Rails on your production server.

If it's your development machine, this can happen when you have rvm installed with different versions of rails.

Comment: Thanks but I have only ever installed Rails 3 so this couldn't have happened. This was an issue with the Bundler gem in the end