# Bundle install to development

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

For some reason when I run `bundle install` it installs to production:

`Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./RAILS_ENV=production`

Arrrghh, how do I switch back to development??

Notes:

- I haven't modified any environment files
- When I run `Rails.env` from the console I get `"development"`

Gem file:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.3'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.3.2', :require => 'sqlite3'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'nokogiri'
  gem 'will_paginate'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec'
end
```

Also worth noting, it creates a folder in my app called `RAILS_ENV=production` which I posted a question about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034230/rails-production-deployment-folder) which now I guess is linked to this issue.

### Update

When I run `bundle config` I get the following information, you can clearly see the Path is set to the culprit! Any ideas how I change this? I tried re-installing the bundler gem but to no avail, maybe this is a bug within Bundler?

```
$ bundle config
Settings are listed in order of priority. The top value will be used.

disable_shared_gems
  Set for your local app (/Users/zinc/ror/site/.bundle/config): "1"

path
  Set for your local app (/Users/zinc/ror/site/.bundle/config): "RAILS_ENV=production"
```

Comment: What does your `Gemfile` look like?

Comment: `bundle config build.libv8 --with-system-v8` is the way to go when using bundler.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The explanation to that is in in the bundler [manual](http://gembundler.com/rationale.html). Read the heading **Grouping Your Dependencies**. Specifically

> Bundler will remember that you installed the gems using --without production. For curious readers, bundler stores the flag in APP_ROOT/.bundle/config. You can see all of the settings that bundler saved there by running bundle config, which will also print out global settings (stored in ~/.bundle/config), and settings set via environment variables. For more information on configuring bundler, please see [Advanced Usage: Configuring Bundler](http://gembundler.com/v1.0/configuring.html).

And the solution is to pass a different value for the property or remove the file APP_ROOT/.bundle/config.

Comment: Good info, although I never ran "--without production" so this appears to be a weird bug

Comment: probably you run it with **RAILS_ENV=production** and bundler remembered that property.

Comment: I answered my own question before you did. However, will accept yours, thanks.

Comment: 10 years later and this is still just as relevant. Bit me this week

Answer (score 3):

Ok I fixed this.

I simply removed the path from my bundle config file and it seems to default back to my original path. I somehow set this accidentally I guess.

Your bundle config file is located in:

```
APP_ROOT/.bundle/config
```

Comment: Yep -- been there - my guess is that you accidentally typed `bundle install RAILS_ENV=production` at some point in the past.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198437/why-did-bundle-create-the-bundle-in-directory-x/ for a tiny bit more info.

Comment: @zinc i don't think you did this accidentally, i happened to me to. The **.bundle** folder is new, my guess it came through a update of Bundle.