# Why did bundle create the bundle in directory X?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I ran

```
bundle install
```

and it completed without error, except that at the very last line, it printed:

```
Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./linecache
```

There's no mention of linecache in the Gemfile.  I even tried the extreme measure of deleting my Gemfile.lock and calling `bundle install` again.  Same result.

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  I had previously typed:

```
bundle install linecache
```

(that's another story).  bundle will `remember` linecache and use that as a directory for subsequent bundles.  The easiest (albeit heavy handed) fix is to delete the .bundle configuration file from your toplevel Rails project directory:

```
rm .bundle/config
```

... and let bundle recreate it the next time you run bundle install.  Slightly cleaner is to edit `your_project_directory/.bundle/config` and delete the line that reads:

```
BUNDLE_PATH: ...
```

Hope this saves someone else some head-scratching.