# bundle install WITH production after installing without production

Tags: ruby, bundler

After having installed my application's gems by executing:

```
bundle install --without production
```

Now I want to install the production group gems. However, when I issue:

```
bundle install
```

bundle seems to remember the previous setting and none of the production group gems are installed. How can I clean this bundle 'cache' and force it to reinstall all the gems in the Gemfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest option is to simply delete the bundle config file located at:

```
.bundle/config
```

within your Rails project then issue the commands:

```
bundle update
bundle install
```

Sources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11198495/1698058) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5040507/1698058).